# Django rest framework DjangoFilterBackend icontains not work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a datetime "2016-03-29T01:45:01.419731Z" in database

This is my Filter :

```
class TaipeiTimeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    taipei_time = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="update_time", lookup_type='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = DataData 
        fields = ['taipei_time',]

class DataList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = DataData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = TaipeiTimeFilter
```

But when I query `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/?taipei_time=2016-03-29`
It found nothing . What's wrong with my Filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icontains` is for approximate string matching.  You are trying to do approximate datetime matching.  For that you are going to need a range of date times. I use a custom filter that I defined for this purpose:

```
from django.db.models import Q
import django_filters

class RangeFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self,qs,value):

        tokens = value.split('..')
        if len(tokens) != 2:
            return qs
        (begin, end) = tokens
        if begin == '' and end == '':
            return qs
        if begin != '' and end != '':
            return qs.filter(Q(**{'%s__range'%self.name:(begin,end)}))
        elif begin != '':
            return qs.filter(Q(**{'%s__gte'%self.name:begin}))
        elif end != '':
            return qs.filter(Q(**{'%s__lte'%self.name:end}))
```

This is used like:

```
taipei_time = RangeFilter(name="update_time")
```

and a query looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/?taipei_time=2016-03-29..2016-03-30
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  And I found I change to ````django_filters.CharFilter````, the ````icontains```` works